# Defender ATP public IP addresses

Tags: microsoft, windows-defender

Does anybody know the IP addresses Microsoft uses for their Defender ATP Service?

I can find the [associated domain names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-atp/configure-server-endpoints-windows-defender-advanced-threat-protection#configure-server-proxy-and-internet-connectivity-settings) but not a reliable source of the IP addresses being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provides an XML file to download with their public Azure IP addresses: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

These IPs can change from time to time as said by John Mahowald.

Answer (score 2):

Name based only.

Those are hosted on Azure public cloud, note azure.com and blob.core.windows.net names. You can assume they won't be in a static subnet, let alone have static IP addresses.

Comment: I've found an downloadable XML file Microsoft provides, containing all their public Azure IP addresses: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653